# Folder name change in Finder but not changed in Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, mojave

iMac running Mojave 10.14.6

I changed a folder name in Finder but I can't see the change in Terminal.

old folder name: A.B

new folder name: A

in Terminal ls still shows A.B

cd . or cd .. then cd back won't change the ls outcome.

in Finder using Go to Folder can go to the new folder name, however the Path bar at the bottom shows the new name but Copy as Pathname or New Terminal at Folder are using the old name.

Restarting the iMac won't fix.

What kind of bug is this? I can fix this by mv in Terminal but I'd prefer the syncing between Finder and Terminal automated.

Comment: Do you have "Hide Extension" set for that folder (or globally)?

Comment: @lhf Thanks for your prompt comment! Follow your suggestion I found "Show all filename extensions" in the Advanced tab of Finder preference (is this what you meant?). It's not ticked by default. I turned it on and the problem is solved. Now I can see that the new folder name is not actually the new name. Please add an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have "Hide extension" set for that folder or have globally disabled "Show all filename extensions" in Finder Advanced preferences.